# Can't vote any more

Tags: support, bug, voting

The vote buttons are dead pictures and don't react, though the middle "show votes" still works.  The flag and up buttons on comments are similarly affected, though they show up after touching the comment.

Is this just me? Is this a known issue? How do I make it work again?
I'm running Firefox on Android, with "desktop" site (not the "mobile" view, which I don't like because the text is way too small)

---

Update: regular (non-beta) Firefox developed the same issue a few days ago. I suspect a bug in FF or irregularly in the site that bothers mobile FF, and the issue I saw in beta just moved to production.

So I uninstalled Firefox.

Comment: Have you tried the [Stack Exchange app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.stackexchange.marvin&hl=en)? I think they did a fairly decent job, though some of the higher level functionality is not available (up/down counts, etc).

Comment: Is it possible you were accidentally logged out?

Comment: How many up/down votes have you cast since midnight UTC? [There are limits as to how many votes you can cast in a day](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5213/255171).

Comment: @Snowman his profile shows 20 votes for the month, so probably not that.  But if you've used your votes for the day you should get a red popup saying "you can vote again in N hours"; the buttons shouldn't just *not work*.  That said, attempting to vote while logged out should also produce feedback, so my prior comment is probably also a red herring.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you've tried just reloading the page.

Have you tried logging out, clearing your cache and cookies, restarting your browser, and then logging in again?

That may reset whatever has got into a funny state.

Comment: This would be my only suggestion as well.

Comment: Tried restarting browser. Logging out and back in does not help. That should reset the cookie.  This doesn't have a cookie manager and the only "clear private data" button would clear *everything* from all pages, which is most annoying to one who uses stong unique passwords.  But...

Comment: I was using Firefox Beta, which does notnshare settings with the release track. The release vwrsion still works.

Answer (score 0):

If you voted a lot today, you can't anymore, for the next 24 hours. The fact that your browser doesn't *tell* you this when you run out of votes is a firefox bug. I have checked on this.

Comment: I was not out of votes, and the problem persisted even after waiting a day. I had to change browsers.